# Contact - Default Currency

Tags: xero-api

In xero-java-sdk:  The contact object has 'DefaultCurrency' field.
While retrieving the Contacts using the sdk, the DefaultCurrency is set as null.
What is the idea of this field?  What is the currency of a Contact in xero?

Answer (score 1):

In Xero's UI a business owner can set the "Default Currency" for a Contact.

Via Xero's API you can retrieve the Contact details including (if they have a default currency).  You mention that it's null on the contact you are looking at.  That would indicate no default currency is set.

Once you've retrieved the default currency from the Contact, you could use it to set the currency on an Invoice you are creating for that contact via the API.

Note, this does not happen automatically.  Xero won't detect a default currency on a Contact and automatically set it on an invoice for you.  You need to make that decision.